# Double click on one cell to change text bold and font color of another cell on the same row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have some code written that was given to me by another user, Twisty (who I seam unable to reply to in the page that was used), which is amazing and what I needed. However, I need it to do a little more. Can anyone help me please?

**This is the code basic code below, which copies the contents of 2 fields to other fields at a double click on each of two chosen cells. And what I also need is for the command line to then Highlight the cell on the same row, so if the row is 223, then highlight cell E223, and then unbold it and convert it to a light grey colour, so I don't need to go to the cell manually and unbold it and change the colour from orange to grey. The cell is bold orange and I want to automatically change it to grey non-bold when I double click a current active double click cell.
I hope that makes sense.

I simply want to double click on the cell that runs the command and have two boxes autofill with the chosen content, aand another cell then gets its contents turned to non-bold text in grey. It will do the sma ewhichever of the two double click cells are selected, so it is one bit of code run whichever cell is clicked for the original code.

The code below works well, so not looking to change it, just want to add the extra bit of code to get the extra work done. It goes in the 'Worksheet 1' code.

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
On Error GoTo Quit
'Copy values between columns on same row that user double-clicks

'Quit if Target range includes more than one cell
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

With ActiveSheet

'Here, specify the worksheet column the user can double-click to activate this
'routine.  For the "B" column, in the Range method specify cell "B1" (all cells
'in column will be used, not just that on row 1).
If Target.Column = .Range("S1").Column Then
    .Cells(Target.Row, .Range("O1").Column) = .Cells(Target.Row, .Range("K1").Column)
    .Cells(Target.Row, .Range("R1").Column) = .Cells(Target.Row, .Range("N1").Column)

    Cancel = True   'Cancel the double-click
End If

'Here you can specify a second "button column" with its own set of copy actions.
If Target.Column = .Range("T1").Column Then
    .Cells(Target.Row, .Range("P1").Column) = .Cells(Target.Row, .Range("H1").Column)
    .Cells(Target.Row, .Range("Q1").Column) = .Cells(Target.Row, .Range("M1").Column)

    Cancel = True   'Cancel the double-click
End If

End With
'Cancel the double-click
Cancel = True

Quit:
End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Below the line that says:

```
.Cells(Target.Row, .Range("R1").Column) = .Cells(Target.Row, .Range("N1").Column)
```

Insert these 3 lines:

```
ThisRow = Target.Row
Cells(ThisRow, 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
Cells(ThisRow, 5).Font.Bold = False
```

Insert them also below the line:

```
.Cells(Target.Row, .Range("Q1").Column) = .Cells(Target.Row, .Range("M1").Column)
```

The "5" references the 5th column, it means in Excel column "E".

The 15 is the ColorIndex for grey. If you don't like it, change it according to this reference:

http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm

Comment: Thank you so much. Did the trick. Thank you for your time.

Comment: As an extra question seeing as you obviously know your stuff, if I have a cell that is the outcome of a calculation of several cells, how do I get that cell Font color to change depending on whather the outcome of the calculation id a posiytive or negative ballance, to say green if it is normal as positive and turning to light red if it is a negative e.g. -$25.00 amount, without me having to go and find it and change it to red?     Thank you again for your time in advance.

Comment: One simple way is to select the cell and in menu go to Home -> Conditional Formatting -> Highlight Cell Rules.

From then, you can select each option (less than, greater than, equal to, etc) and the format you want for the cell.

Comment: Thankyou that works well. Thanks again for your valuable time. Very much appreciated.